# previous data losted when click on add button in GirdView in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i am working on Asp.Net with C#-4.0 .
I want to get Input from end user in a GridView. Like

[image]

in DropDownList or in TextBox i enters some value and clicks on Add then new record will add but previous data was lost.

[image]

the Problem is when i change value of controls, it not saves in DataTable to which it is binded. How can i save this value to DataTable. What code i have missed here  ?

designer code :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SaleOrder.aspx.cs" Inherits="Transactions_SaleOrder" %>

<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
        </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FormHeader" Runat="Server">
    <p>Sale Order</p>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="FormBody" Runat="Server">
    <table class="style1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text="Date : "></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSODate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:CalendarExtender ID="txtSODate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
                    Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtSODate" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" PopupButtonID="ImageButton1">
                </asp:CalendarExtender>
                <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="txtSODate_MaskedEditExtender" runat="server" 
                Enabled="True" Mask="99/99/9999" MaskType="Date" TargetControlID="txtSODate">
                </asp:MaskedEditExtender>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl="~/images/Calendar_scheduleHS.png" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Shift : 
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="300px">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Morning">MORNING</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="EVENING"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="OTHERS"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
                    onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProduct" runat="server" Width="300"
                                DataSource='<%# dtProductMaster %>'
                                DataTextField="PDescr"
                                DataValueField="PID"
                                >
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qty">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuan" runat="server" MaxLength="5" style="text-align:right" Text='<%# BIND("QUAN") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="txtQuan_MaskedEditExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" 
                                    Mask="99999" TargetControlID="txtQuan">
                                </asp:MaskedEditExtender>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="ADD" Text="Add" />
                        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="DELETE" Text="Delete" />
                    </Columns>
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                </asp:GridView>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" Width="58px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="FormFooter" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

C# Code behind it :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
public partial class Transactions_SaleOrder : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    internal DataTable dtProductMaster_;
    internal DataTable dtProductMaster
    {
        get
        {
            if (dtProductMaster_ == null)
            {
                clsData d = new clsData();
                d.Select("select PID, PEDESCR2 + ' ' + PEDESCR3 as PDescr From TBLPROD_MAST");
                dtProductMaster_ = d.DataTable;
            }
            return dtProductMaster_;
        }
    }
    DataTable dtProductDet
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["dtProductDet"] != null)
            {
                return (DataTable)ViewState["dtProductDet"];
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["dtProductDet"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            txtSODate.Text = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            //--
            dtProductDet = new DataTable("dtProductDet");
            dtProductDet.Columns.Add("PID", typeof(int));
            dtProductDet.Columns.Add("PName", typeof(string));
            dtProductDet.Columns.Add("Quan", typeof(decimal));
            dtProductDet.Rows.Add(0,"",0);
            //--
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = dtProductDet;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.CommandName.ToUpper())
        {
            case "ADD":
                dtProductDet.Rows.Add(0, "", 0);
                break;
            case "DELETE":
                dtProductDet.Rows.RemoveAt(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

how can i achieve my aim.

Comment: Looks like you are rebinding the gridview on postback. You should put the last two lines in to the `!IsPostback` block.

Comment: i tried, but new row in not adding now.

Comment: You need to rebind in the click handler, after the data has been added to the datasource. `Page_Load` is called before the handler.

Comment: but entered data is not saving back to DataTable, i checked data table in RowCommand event, DataRow in empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution.

The problem is, when i am editing value in DropDownList or in TextBox, its value is not saving back to DataTable which is bind with GridView and TextBox and DropDownList.
There is no automatic way to do this, so we have to write manual code to save values back to DataTable.

When i asked the question add button was in GridViewColumn and it was command Column, now i have added a button in GridView Footer.

So when i click on "Add new row" button, page is posted back, at first page load event fires and then Button_Click event fires. I have add code on Page.Load event, if page is posted back then pick data from GridView and Save it to DataTable.

Nextly Button_click event fires, so a new row adds in DataTable and DataTable will assign in DataSource of GridView and DataBind method executes and re-generates GridView.

I have a DropDownList which is also bind to a different DataTable other than GridView, so that after DataBind() i have to select manually value in DropDownList as per saved in DataTable of GridView.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        txtSODate.Text = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        //--
        dtProductDet = new DataTable("dtProductDet");
        dtProductDet.Columns.Add("PID", typeof(int));
        dtProductDet.Columns.Add("PName", typeof(string));
        dtProductDet.Columns.Add("Quan", typeof(decimal));
        dtProductDet.Rows.Add(0,"",0);
        //--
        SetGridViewSource();
    }
    else
    {
        DataTable dtPD = dtProductDet;
        DropDownList ddlProd = null;
        if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                ddlProd = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[gvci_Prod].FindControl("ddlProduct");
                dtPD.Rows[i]["PID"] = Convert.ToInt32(ddlProd.SelectedItem.Value);
                dtPD.Rows[i]["PName"] = ddlProd.SelectedItem.Text;
                dtPD.Rows[i]["QUAN"] = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[gvci_Quan].FindControl("txtQuan")).Text;
            }
        }
        dtProductDet = dtPD;
    }
}


protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dtProductDet.Rows.Add(0, "", 0);

    DataTable dtPDet = dtProductDet;
    GridView1.DataSource = dtPDet;
    GridView1.DataBind();


    DropDownList ddlProd = null;
    DataRow drFind = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        ddlProd = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[gvci_Prod].FindControl("ddlProduct");
        drFind = dtProductMaster.Rows.Find(dtPDet.Rows[i]["PID"]);
        if(drFind != null)
        {
            ddlProd.SelectedIndex = dtProductMaster.Rows.IndexOf(drFind);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer has already been given in previous comments. To spell it out...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        txtSODate.Text = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        //--
        dtProductDet = new DataTable("dtProductDet");
        dtProductDet.Columns.Add("PID", typeof(int));
        dtProductDet.Columns.Add("PName", typeof(string));
        dtProductDet.Columns.Add("Quan", typeof(decimal));
        dtProductDet.Rows.Add(0,"",0);
        //--
        GridView1.DataSource = dtProductDet;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CommandName.ToUpper())
    {
        case "ADD":
            dtProductDet.Rows.Add(0, "", 0);
            break;
        case "DELETE":
            dtProductDet.Rows.RemoveAt(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
            break;
    }
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: its not working, although next time when page load, no record is displayed in grid

Comment: What exactly is not working? Is the blank row not being added into the DataTable when you click the add button?

Comment: Gridview in not displayed on page, when click on Add button.

Comment: If you put your Page_Load event back to the way it was, and then try again - GridView1 should be visible. When you click on the add button your RowCommand event will add a blank line into the DataTable and you should see this in GirdView1 when the postback completes - is this happening?

Comment: yes, it is happening, if i put databind out side of !Page.IsPostBack block